# UILabel and getting the size after autofit

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, font-size

I have an instance of `UILabel` with a default font size of `28` and minimum font size of `16`. I allow the font to auto-adjust to fit subject to this minimum and with one line only.

Suppose I have some text in the `UILabel` that has been automatically adjusted to fit. How do I get the new font size, or to be more precise the scale factor applied to the label's content?

[NB. The font property does not change under autofit.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that this calculation is done at draw time and not accessible (at least using public apis)

But you should be able to calculate it using one of `UIKit` [`sizeWithFont:` methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html), like `UILabel` does. *(Beware that text metrics are CPU consuming... like when using them in a table cell)*

Comment: @VG: Thanks for the answer. I feared so. Since I only need to do the calculation once, I can afford to try this and take the `MAX` with the declared minimum font size.